# Is there any way to compress png files in android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using bitmap.Compress(format.png, 80, out) function in Xamarin.Android but the out is always some more bytes in image files size. I don't want WebP format and require png file with compressed format.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: PNG already is compressed (lossless) - so when you compress something compressed it nearly always gets bigger.

Comment: Quality compression has no effect on images in the PNG format because PNG is lossless compression，you could try "bitmap.Compress(format.jpeg, 80, out)".

Comment: do you want the end image file to be a png? If yes then no you cannot do that because if you do it and if i am correct it wont help at all with your compression

Comment: @Leo, png has transparent pixels, converting to jpg will looses its alpha channel

Comment: @G.hakim I used ARG8888 configuration for converting,  I also tried using Alpha8 configuration but no luck. Can't we maintain alpha channel and try to reduce png's

Comment: Well that is the point you can't in my knowledge